# Usage of InverseTransformPoint on rotated object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I develop script for 2D grid that "lives" in 3D environment. The model of the grid is a two-dimensional array. The grid should be 
modifiable - support for changing position, scale and rotation. One of the required functions is to get grid indexes (array[i, j]) 
on mouse over. The script works OK while rotation is 0,0,0. There are no problems neither with moving nor with scaling, but if grid is rotated, then wrong indexes are returned. I use transform.InverseTransformPoint to convert world position of mouse to local coordinates on grid.

The relevant part of the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GridManager: MonoBehaviour {

    //...   
    public float    tileSize = 0.6f;    //tile size, tile width == tile hight

    private Object[, ] grid;
    private Vector3 gridBottomLeftLocal;


    void Start() {
        //...
        //grid start position is 0, y, 0
        gridBottomLeftLocal = new Vector3 (-gridSizeX / 2, transform.position.y, -gridSizeY / 2);
    }

    void Update() {
        Vector3 mousePos;
        if (getMousePosition(out mousePos)) {
            Debug.Log ("Hit");
            Vector2 tile = getTileByWorldPos(mousePos);
            Debug.Log ("Pos: " + tile);
        }
    }

    //TODO: check for out of grid bounds
    Vector2 getTileByWorldPos (Vector3 worldPos) {
        Vector3 localPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPos);
        Vector3 offset = localPos - gridBottomLeftLocal;
        int x = (offset.x % tileSize == 0) ? (int)(offset.x / tileSize) - 1: (int)(offset.x / tileSize);
        int y = (offset.z % tileSize == 0) ? (int)(offset.z / tileSize) - 1: (int)(offset.z / tileSize);
        return new Vector2 (x, y);
    }

    private bool getMousePosition(out Vector3 mousePos) {
        Vector3 a = transform.position + Vector3.forward;
        Vector3 b = transform.position + Vector3.right;
        Vector3 c = transform.position + new Vector3 (1,0,1);
        Plane plane = new Plane (a, b, c);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        float enter;
        bool isHit = plane.Raycast (ray, out enter);
        mousePos = isHit ? ray.GetPoint (enter) : Vector3.zero;
        return isHit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the mouse position with `Debug` class to verify that it is calculated correctly with rotated grid?

Comment: `gridBottomLeftLocal` is calculated as world position, but used as local position in `getTileByWorldPos`

Comment: Also, `gridBottomLeftLocal` is calculated as if the object never moves (once at the start and never again), but the plane is created every frame, as if the object moves in runtime. Does the object move in runtime or not?

Comment: You use `transform.position.y`, which is world coordinate. If it's a local coordinate, it should stay the same regardless of the world coordinates of the transform, but it doesn't. So `gridBottomLeftLocal` is not a local coordinate. I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: If we would interpret it as a local coordinate, it would mean that for every unit transform goes up, this thing goes up **twice**. Because, translated to world coordinates, `transform.TransformPoint(gridBottomLeftLocal).y == 2 * transform.position.y`

Comment: 1) Yes. My expectation was that InverseTransform takes rotation "in to account". 
2) gridBottomLeftLocal is calculated only once, on start as local -  grid has no parents, so local position == world position and start point is 0,0,0 (I put this values on start);
3) Object moves. But I use object transform.position to create plane. This position changed when object moves.

Comment: (1) It should, and that's why I'm confused by your error. What is your "yes" answering (these comments are very limiting)? (2) When you base your code correctness on assumptions like "grid has no parents, so local position == world position", it becomes very fragile and hard to maintain. I would refrain from doing this. It also makes code hard to read (that's why I was confused).

Comment: So, what about testing mouse position with `Debug`, have you tried it?

Comment: The "Yes" was answer on this question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. These comments are confusing.

Comment: By the way, if you just want this to work, I think that if you make a parent for the board and rotate the parent instead of the board itself, it will. I'm still confused with the world/local coordinate system rotation though.

Comment: I think that I have to use another approach (not only InverseTransform ) to translate coordinates, but I didn't find  examples on i-net.

Comment: If you want to rotate the point manually, you can use this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix

Comment: The problem solved. It was in plane creation.  The modified code calculates 3 grid positions (corners) on grid creation and in  getMousePosition() uses  transform.TransformPoint to convert these  local positions to  world positions of the plane.

Comment: Can you please post corrected code in an answer? I'm really curious what this was all about.